# WEB API 2 Routing issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api-routing

"message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:64221/api/companies/lncr/Orders/00029303_070/Lines/6'.",

"messageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'PurchLines' that matches the request."

```
[RoutePrefix("api/companies/{compId}/Orders/{orderId}/Lines")]
public class PurchLinesController : BaseApiController
{
    public PurchLinesController(IPortalReposotry repo)
        : base(repo)
    {

    }

    [Route("")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(String compId, String orderId, int levelOfDetails = 1)
    {
        IQueryable<PurchLine> query;

        if (levelOfDetails == 1)
        {
            query = PortalReposotry.GetPurchasLines(compId, orderId);
        }
        else
        {
            query = PortalReposotry.GetPurchasLinesWithApprovalHist(compId, orderId);
        }

        if (query.Count() == 0)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        var results = query.ToList()
                           .Select(v => this.ModelFactory.Create(v));


        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, results);
    }

    [Route("{lineId:double}" , Name="line")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Get(String compId, String purchId, double lineId, int levelOfDetails = 1)
    {
        PurchLine results;
        if (levelOfDetails == 1)
        {
            results = PortalReposotry.GetPurchasLine(compId, purchId, lineId);
        }
        else
        {
            results = PortalReposotry.GetPurchasLineWithApprovalHist(compId, purchId, lineId);
        }

        if (results == null)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, ModelFactory.Create(results));
    }
}
```

The request should be matching the second Get request.
**api/companies/{compId}/Orders/{orderId}/Lines/{lineId}**
http://localhost:64221/api/companies/lncr/Orders/00029303_070/Lines/6

The lineId is a type of double, I have also tried
http://localhost:64221/api/companies/lncr/Orders/00029303_070/Lines/6.0/

But that didn't work either so I am sort of at a loss here to what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error, the second get response had the purchId but my RoutePrefix was defined as orderId.  easy oversight.